# Hidden Laravel Methods (5.1)

Tags: laravel, methods

First, I have IDE helper, and the php storm plugin. I tried the Gist pre made too. There are some similar questions, but no one seems to get answers. I'll probably poke laracasts and ide helper bug list if I don't get anything here.

So I'm following along to some of the into laracasts, and the guy keeps using methods that are not defined as far as I can tell. Situation:

I created a eloquent model called Article. It extends

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

So now I have App\Article and I can call any of the methods available to model. For example:

```
$article = \App\Article::all();
```

PHPStorm is happy. He keeps pulling stuff like `::find()` or `::findOrFail()`

It's in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

I just don't under stand how that works, I don't see the methods defined in model. If this is what ide helper is supposed to fix, then I'm not certain it's working correctly. I can RTFM, I'm pretty sure I followed the directions to a tee.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't get autocomplete for all methods, or that you get them but just don't understand where the `all`, `find` and `findOrFail` come from?

Comment: That I don't get auto complete for all methods, but I guess I also don't understand where they come from. If it's not defined in that file, how does it even exist?

Comment: Since the methods don't exist in the `Model`, the call will get picked up by the [magic](http://bit.ly/1I778yt) [`__call`](http://bit.ly/1MuZNg3) method, which in turn creates a new Query Builder instance and tries to run the method on that instance. That is an instance of the class [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder](http://bit.ly/1MuZLVC) which **does** have the methods defined. The trick here is that when you try call a method that doesn't exits in the Model, it delegates the call and tries to run it on the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries).

Comment: That's an excellent explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya know, I just found it. I see this question out and about, so I'll answer it here.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/248#issuecomment-131503475

Fixed find or fail for me. find is still MIA. I'm surprised laravel doesn't support their code base in the forms of plugins or dedicated IDE's bit more. It's all just people out there creating a community and moving the world forward so I can't complain too much.

Comment: I accepted my own, because this is a fix to my issue. But @bogdan answers the actual question:
 
Since the methods don't exist in the Model, the call will get picked up by the magic __call method, which in turn creates a new Query Builder instance and tries to run the method on that instance. That is an instance of the class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder which does have the methods defined. The trick here is that when you try call a method that doesn't exits in the Model, it delegates the call and tries to run it on the Query Builder. – Bogdan Nov 22 at 2:23

Answer (score 0):

It works because `Model` implements `__callStatic()` which dispatches it to itself on a new instance: [__callStatic() implementation on Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bc63ea2e6feee5ce5584adec66b0ecc34e7455eb/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3492-L3497)

It creates a new instance (`new static`) of the model in question and dispatches the statically called method on the instance.

Effectively, `Model::foo($bar)` is the same as `(new Model)->foo($bar)`.